# Yii2 issue to get the result for db query

Tags: php, yii2

I am using this command to get if the record already exist in the database;

```
$query = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `order_item` 
WHERE `date` = '$date'  AND `start_time` = '$starttime'), 1, 0)");

$result=$query->queryAll();

var_dump($result);exit;
```

Now the result I am getting for dump is like:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `order_item` 
WHERE `date` = '2018-12-03' AND `start_time` = '10:15:00'), 1, 0)"]=> string(1) "0" } }
```

whereas I want the result as just `1` or `0`
like

```
if ($result==1){
//do something;
}
```

as if I am running the same query in phpmyadmin - I am getting the result as `0` or `1`

How I can achieve the same from the Query in Yii2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`queryAll()` returns all fields from all rows as arrays. If you want to get single value from first field of first row, you need to use [`queryScalar()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#queryScalar()-detail).

```
$result = $query->queryScalar();
```

Comment: Hi rob006 - can you help me build a query like I am comparing ordered classes with the booked classes. so instead of generally telling for unavailabilty, I can tell more specifically which slot is not available and to remove that specific slot.